# Blank page on upgrading ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have upgraded by `ionic 2.1.17 to 2.1.18` using these commands:

```
npm uninstall ionic -g
npm uninstall cordova -g
npm cache clean
npm install cordova -g
npm install ionic -g
```

after that I installed a fresh ionic with sidemenus as :

```
ionic start --v2 test_project sidemenu
```

Now in test_project I replaced src of my original project (containing ionic 2.1.17)

currently I am having ionic 2.1.18..

The issue is that now I am getting only a Blank screen .

****  When i am hitting it in firefox it works fine but in chrome i am getting blank page.

In chrome console i am getting:

```
reactive_errors.js:28
  It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
  when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
  you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.

  Example: 
  form = new FormGroup({
    first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
    last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
  });
```

and,

```
plugin.js:33 Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
```

** getting same error for android version greater than 5 also their also getting blank page on installing app.

This is my sys. info :

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.47
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v6.9.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Any help please

Comment: try to use chrome incognito

Comment: @Jinje: I tried it but no luck I request you to look at my updated question.

Comment: I want to add that same error i am getting in firefox also .. but their app is running fine any guess whats the issue at all ??